# Geodesics on a 2D flat round metric/2 contradicting results

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, geodesics

I was solving the geodesics of $$ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\phi^2$$ for an exercise. Using as an affine parameter the coordinate $\phi$ I arrived at the equations:

- $\frac{d^2r}{d\phi^2}-r=0$
- $\frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{d\phi}=0$

One of them gives out hypebrbolics while the other gives a constant function. In the execise I am hinted at that the solution should involve 2 integration constants. A next question asks to prove that the geodesics are straight lines. My understanding is that the constant function is somehow discarded but I don't understand why. Could anyone help me understand? Is it that the constant function is just a subcase of the hyperbolic one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember 2 main things:

1. in some problems there are some **independent variables** and some **dependent variables** (depending on the independent variables); you're not free to set dependent variables as you wish, since they're not free to be set, but depends on the model and the independent variables
2. that vectors/tensors are not only components, but these components are referred to a basis, and when you're not using a Cartesian basis some "unexpected" things (if you forgot the basis) may happen.

Let's start by saying that the geodesic equation
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{0} = \left( \ddot{q}^k + \dot{q}^l \dot{q}^m \Gamma_{lm}^k  \right) \mathbf{b}_k \ ,
\end{equation}
using the coordinates $(r(\tau), \phi(\tau))$, given the non-zero Christoffel symbols
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_{\phi \phi}^r = -r \qquad , \qquad \qquad \Gamma_{\phi r}^{\phi} = \Gamma_{r \phi}^{\phi} = \frac{1}{r} \ ,
\end{equation}
has components
\begin{equation}\begin{cases}
  \ddot{r} - r \dot{\phi}^2 = 0 \\
  \ddot{\phi} + \dfrac{2}{r} \dot{\phi} \dot{r} = 0 \ .
\end{cases}\end{equation}
This is the system of ODE you need to solve for $r(\tau)$, $\phi(\tau)$, without doing strange things like prescribing a part of the solution, like you do if **you set $\phi(\tau) = \tau$**. **You can't do it!**, since $\tau$ is an independent variable, while $\phi$ is a dependent variable or function of $\tau$.

Now, writing the equation of a curve using Cartesian coordinates,
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{r}(\tau) = x(\tau) \mathbf{\hat{x}} + y(\tau) \mathbf{\hat{y}} \ ,
\end{equation}
linking the Cartesian coordinates with the polar coordinates
\begin{equation}\begin{cases}
  x(\tau) & = r(\tau) \cos \phi(\tau) \\
  y(\tau) & = r(\tau) \sin \phi(\tau) \\
\end{cases}\end{equation}
and computing the first and second order derivatives of $\mathbf{r}$,
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  \dot{\mathbf{r}} & = \left( \dot{r} \cos\phi - r\dot{\phi} \sin{\phi} \right) \mathbf{\hat{x}} + \left( \dot{r} \sin\phi + r\dot{\phi} \cos{\phi} \right) \\
  \ddot{\mathbf{r}} & = \left( \ddot{r} \cos\phi - 2\dot{r}\dot{\phi} \sin{\phi} - r\ddot{\phi}\sin{\phi} - r\dot{\phi}^2\cos\phi \right) \mathbf{\hat{x}} + \\ 
  & + \left( \ddot{r} \sin\phi + 2 \dot{r}\dot{\phi} \cos{\phi} + r\ddot{\phi}\cos{\phi} - r\dot{\phi}^2\sin\phi \right) \mathbf{\hat{y}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
and now, writing the relation between the vectors of the Cartesian basis and the natural base induced by the choice of the polar coordinates
\begin{equation}\begin{cases}
  \mathbf{\hat{x}} = \cos \phi \mathbf{b}_r - \frac{1}{r} \sin \phi \mathbf{b}_{\phi} \\
  \mathbf{\hat{y}} = \sin \phi \mathbf{b}_r + \frac{1}{r} \cos \phi \mathbf{b}_{\phi} \ ,
\end{cases}\end{equation}
it should be easy to get
\begin{equation}
  \ddot{\mathbf{r}} = \left( \ddot{r} - r\dot{\phi}^2 \right) \mathbf{b}_r + \left( \ddot{\phi} + \frac{2}{r} \dot{\phi} \dot{r} \right) \mathbf{b}_{\phi} \ .
\end{equation}
Thus, being the components equal to zero by the geodesic equation, it follows that $\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = \mathbf{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get your equation? Normally, starting from the action given by the arclength:
$$
S=\int \sqrt{\left(\frac{dr}{d\phi}\right)^2+r^2}d\phi
$$
You should just get one Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$
\frac{d}{d\phi}\left(\frac{\frac{dr}{d\phi}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{dr}{d\phi}\right)^2+r^2}}\right)-\frac{r}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{dr}{d\phi}\right)^2+r^2}}=0
$$
which simplifies to:
$$
\frac{d^2r}{d\phi^2}-\frac2r\left(\frac{dr}{d\phi}\right)^2-r=0
$$
In any case, since you know you want straight lines, hyperbolic functions in polar coordinates cannot be the right solutions.

Equivalently, you can parametrize by the arclength and get:
$$
\begin{align}
0&= \frac{d^2r}{ds^2}-r\left(\frac{d\phi}{ds}\right)^2\\
0&= \frac{d}{ds}\left(r^2\frac{d\phi}{ds}\right)
\end{align}
$$
And convert it back to an equation in $\phi$ only using the differential definition of the arclength.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use polar coordinates to calculate geodesics in the flat plane isn't the smartest thing to do but perhaps a good exercise.

The non zero Christoffel symbols are
\begin{align}
\Gamma^r_{\phi\phi}&=-r\,,&\Gamma^\phi_{r\phi}=\Gamma^\phi_{\phi r}=\frac 1r\,.
\end{align}
The geodesic equations are therefore
\begin{align}\tag{1}
0&=\ddot r-r\,{\dot\phi}^2\,,&0&=\ddot\phi+\frac 2r\dot r\dot\phi\,.
\end{align}
It looks like what you did was to use $\phi$ as the parameter for $r$ which
leads to $\dot\phi=1$ and $\ddot\phi=0$ turning (1) into your two ODEs
\begin{align}
0&=\ddot r-r\,,&0&=\frac{\dot r}{r}=\frac d{dt}\log r\,.
\end{align}
Obviously though this system has no solutions because the second equation implies $r=const.$ which contradicts the first equation unless $r=0$ but this is singular in polar coordinates.

Multiplying the second ODE in (1) by $r^2$ turns this into
$$
0=r^2\,\ddot\phi+2\,r\,\dot r\,\dot\phi=\frac{d}{dt}\Big(r^2\dot\phi\Big)
$$
which is
$$
r^2\dot\phi=C\,.
$$
This turns (1) into
$$\tag{2}
0=\ddot r\,r^3-C^2\,,\quad r^2\dot\phi=C\,. 
$$

The simplest solutions are straight lines through the origin
\begin{align}
r&=r_0+vt\,,&\phi&=const.
\end{align}
but they cannot be parametrized by $\phi\,.$

It is easy to rewrite other straight lines from Cartesian to polar coordinates
\begin{align}
%x(t)&=x_0+v_xt\,,&y(t)&=y_0+v_y\,t\,,\\
r(t)&=\sqrt{(x_0+v_xt)^2+(y_0+v_yt)^2}\,,\\
\phi(t)&=\arccos\Big(\frac{x_0+v_xt}{r(t)}\Big)
\end{align}
but it is very cumbersome to check that $r$ and $\phi$ satisfy (1). I did this with Wolfram Alpha.

From the point of view of (2) it is not that astonishing anymore that $\phi$ cannot be a parameter for $r$ because the second equation $r^2\dot\phi=C$ then implies that
$r$ is constant and the first ODE implies that $C=0\,.$